# Integrating PayPal with backend that uses authentication headers

Tags: javascript, node.js, paypal

```
var create_payment_json = {
        intent: "sale",

    payer: {
        payment_method: "paypal"
    },
    
    redirect_urls: {
        return_url: "http://0c95effc2751.ngrok.io/success",
        cancel_url: "http://0c95effc2751.ngrok.io/cancel"
    },...}



 paypal.payment.create(create_payment_json, function (error, payment) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error)
            throw error;
        } else {
            for(let i = 0;i < payment.links.length;i++){
              if(payment.links[i].rel === 'approval_url'){
                console.log(payment.links[i].href)
           
               res.redirect(payment.links[i].href);
              }
            }
        }
      });
```

In my backend Node.js code, I use middleware to require authentication so all routes are accessible with authorization header.  After payment approval on a PayPal page, the redirection back to the success route happens without this authorization header, so the success route is unfortunately inaccessible. How can this be resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution is to **not use any redirects**. At all.

Instead, make two routes on your server, one for 'Create Order' and one for 'Capture Order', [documented here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/#server-side-api-calls). These routes should return only JSON data (no HTML or text). The latter one should (on success) store the payment details in your database before it does the return (particularly `purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0].id`, the PayPal transaction ID)

Pair those two routes with the following approval flow: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

Comment: please how can i implement Set up server-side SDK and create an order in my code , the las one contain index file who require express , routes files and authentification requirement, in my routes there is payement route

Comment: Not sure what you're asking for help with specifically; the necessary steps are documented in the above.